# pdo mysql using count

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I used to be able to do this using

```
      $userid = 1;
      mysql_query('
          SELECT sum(a) from (
              select COUNT(*) as a, userTable.userid, followTable.followingid, shareTable.postid
              FROM userTable
              INNER JOIN followTable
              INNER JOIN shareTable
                  ON followTable.followingid = userTable.userid
                  AND shareTable.userid = followTable.followingid
              WHERE followTable.userid = $userid
              UNION ALL
              SELECT count(*) as a, userTable.userid, Null as nullcolumn, shareTable.postid
              FROM userTable
              INNER JOIN shareTable ON shareTable.userid = userTable.userid
              WHERE shareTable.userid = $userid
          ) as sumofcount');
```

and use fetch for the values. However with PDO this does not seem to work

This is what I'm doing with PDO

```
$streamquery  = '
    SELECT sum(a) from (
        select COUNT(*) as a, userTable.userid, followTable.followingid, shareTable.postid
        FROM userTable
        INNER JOIN followTable
        INNER JOIN shareTable
            ON followTable.followingid = userTable.userid
            AND shareTable.userid = followTable.followingid
        WHERE followTable.userid = :userid
        UNION ALL
        SELECT count(*) as heey, userTable.userid, Null as nullcolumn, shareTable.postid 
        FROM userTable
        INNER JOIN shareTable ON shareTable.userid = userTable.userid
        WHERE shareTable.userid = :userid
    ) as sumofcount';
$querystream = $conn->prepare($streamquery);
$querystream->execute(array("userid"=>$userid);
```

After the query I get an empty set.

Comment: Do you get an empty resultset? Do you get an exception? Please explain more! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first, you seem to be missing the `ON` condition for the `followTable` join. I assume MySQL just does something weird here but it might be worth your while looking in to that. I think it should be

```
FROM userTable
INNER JOIN followTable
    ON followTable.followingid = userTable.userid
INNER JOIN shareTable
    ON shareTable.userid = followTable.followingid
```

but could be interpreting your (query) intentions incorrectly.

The real problem is that you cannot re-use named placeholders in a statement. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/pdo.prepare.php)

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement

I suggest you set PDO to throw exceptions when it encounters an error. I assume your `prepare` call is failing silently so use this after you create your connection...

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Now use two different markers in your query, eg

```
... WHERE followTable.userid = :userid1
// snip
... WHERE shareTable.userid = :userid2
```

and execute with the same...

```
$querystream->execute(array(
    ':userid1' => $userid,
    ':userid2' => $userid));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this code. I hope it works for you as it worked for me.

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:dbname=your_db_name;host=127.0.0.1;', 'root', 'password');
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM table_name";
$result = $connection->query($query);
$num_rows = $result->fetchColumn(0)
```

Basically, what this code does is setting the connection (first line), then write down your query using at least the sintax "count(*)" and then you execute the query and fetch the column with the info required. Probably there are more efficient ways, but this is the way I use.

Comment: my query is not as simple as count from one table. I need to do a join first and cout the results from the table

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the PDO prepare statement to look for ":userid" key in the execute array and are using "userid" when you are executing the statement instead of ":userid"

Try this

```
$streamquery = 'SELECT sum(a) FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS a, userTable.userid, followTable.followingid, shareTable.postid FROM userTable INNER JOIN followTable INNER JOIN shareTable ON followTable.followingid = userTable.userid AND shareTable.userid = followTable.followingid WHERE followTable.userid = :userid UNION ALL SELECT  count(*) AS heey, userTable.userid,  Null AS nullcolumn, shareTable.postid FROM userTable INNER JOIN shareTable ON shareTable.userid = userTable.userid WHERE shareTable.userid = :userid) AS sumofcount ';
$querystream = $conn->prepare($streamquery);
$querystream->execute(array(":userid" => $userid);
```

Note I replaced

```
$querystream->execute(array("userid" => $userid);
```

with

```
$querystream->execute(array(":userid" => $userid);
```

Comment: i've used $querystream->execute(array("userid" => $userid) for other prepared statements with :userid in another simple query and it works. I'm not sure that is the problem

Comment: Did you try the edit i made ? If yes , does the query still not work ?

Comment: PHP automatically includes the `:` prefix if the user omits it in bound parameter names